# POST call not returning a result from REST API to iPhone App

Tags: php, ios, rest

I'm having trouble getting the iPhone App to send a POST correctly with my API. When the call is made, no result is returned at all.

1. The POST call is intended to send a message (store the message, check against some parameters, and initiate a 'push' notification)
2. The post call works from a form on a .php file but not when used through the app.
   Returns the result:

   > {"message":{"message":{"saved":1}},"pushed":1,"error":[]}

   The error during the push is expected because test2.php is not sending the message to a mobile device, just the database.
3. Here is the POST code for the app

   ```
   NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
   NSString *time = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
   NSLog(@"time : %@", time);
   NSLog(@"message : %@", self.messageTxt.text);

   NSString *urlString = [[Utils getSendMessageUrl] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request setValue:[UserSession sharedInstance].customerTableNum forHTTPHeaderField:@"point"];
   [request setValue:[UserSession sharedInstance].locationId forHTTPHeaderField:@"location"];
   [request setValue:time forHTTPHeaderField:@"sent"];
   [request setValue:self.messageTxt.text forHTTPHeaderField:@"message"];
   [request setValue:[UserSession sharedInstance].phoneNumber forHTTPHeaderField:@"number"];

   self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
   NSURLConnection *sendConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
   [sendConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
   [sendConnection start];
   ```

What could be causing the app to load index.php with no result? The post variables are set correctly and even if the 'push' fails, the message should still be entered into the database (as the test2.php does successfully).

----------- EDIT ----------------

Here's a response from my app developer:

```
pragma mark - NSURLConnection delegate


  (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
     NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
     [self.receivedData setLength:0];
 }

 (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
 {
     NSLog(@"didReceiveData : %@", data);
     [self.receivedData appendData:data];
  }
  
  (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
      NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
 }
 
  (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
     NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"result : %@", resultS tring);
      
      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didSendMessage:) withObject:resultString waitUntilDone:NO];
  }


I get the following log.

    2012-04-11 00:13:59.177 M[7682:707] didReceiveResponse
 
    2012-04-11 00:13:59.179 M[7682:707] result : 

    No header response is sent back.
```

The request requires the following:

- location (number)
- point (number)
- number (number)
- message (string)
- sent (datetime: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)

Here's a PHP code sans the security portions to reduce the length.

1. The call that handles everything starting at case = post (the get is for retrieving messages)

   ```
   $request = RestUtils::processRequest();

   switch ($request->getMethod()){
       case 'get':
       case 'post':
           $db = get_db();
           $response = array();
           $response["message"] = array();     
           $data = $request->getRequestVars();
           $location = htmlspecialchars($data["location"]);
           $point = htmlspecialchars($data["point"]);
           $area = get_area($point, $location, $db);
           $employee = get_employee($request, $area, $db);
           $message_id = add_message($response["message"], $request, $area, $db);      
           if($employee == false){
               $response["error"] = "mo.";
               $response["pushed"] = 0;
               RestUtils::sendResponse(410, json_encode($response), 'application/json');
               exit;
           }
           $response["pushed"] = array();
           $response["error"] = array();
           $number = htmlspecialchars($data['number']);
           switch($employee["phone_Type"]){
               case 1:
                   if(is_blocked($number)){
                       $response["error"] = "You're Number is Blocked";
                       $response["pushed"] = 0;
                       RestUtils::sendResponse(503, json_encode($response), 'application/json');
                       exit;
                   }
                   if(push_android($employee["device_ID"], $message_id, $point, $location) == false){
                       $response["error"] = "Service Temporally Unavailable";
                       $response["pushed"] = 0;
                       RestUtils::sendResponse(400, json_encode($response), 'application/json');
                       exit;
                   }
                   $response["pushed"] = 1;
                   break;
               case 2:
                   if(is_blocked($number)){
                       $response["error"] = "You're Number is Blocked";
                       $response["pushed"] = 0;
                       RestUtils::sendResponse(503, json_encode($response), 'application/json');
                       exit;
                   }
                   push_iOS($employee["device_ID"], $message_id, $point, $location);
                   $response["pushed"] = 1;
                   break;
               default:
                   $response["pushed"] = 0;
                   $response["error"] = 'Unsupported Phone Type';
                   RestUtils::sendResponse(406, json_encode($response), 'application/json');
           }
           $db->close();
           RestUtils::sendResponse(200, json_encode($response), 'application/json');
           break;
   }
   ```
2. And here's the supporting functions:

   ```
   function build_post_query($area, $point, $location, $message, $number, $sent){
       return "INSERT INTO messages (message_ID, area_ID, point_ID, location_ID, message_Sent, message_Text, message_Number, message_Viewed) VALUES (NULL, ".$area.", ".$point.", ".$location.", '".$sent."', '".$message."', '".$number."', 0)";
   }

   function add_message(&$response, $request, $area, $db){
       $data = $request->getRequestVars();
       $point = htmlspecialchars($data["point"]);
       $location = htmlspecialchars($data["location"]);
       $area = get_area($point, $location, $db);
       $sent = htmlspecialchars($data["sent"]);// 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss' format from users phone
       $message = htmlspecialchars($data["message"]);
       $number = htmlspecialchars($data["number"]);
       $query = build_post_query($area, $point, $location, $message, $number, $sent);
       $result = $db->query($query);
       $response["message"] = array('saved'=>$db->affected_rows);
       $message_id = $db->insert_id;

       return $message_id;
   }

   function get_area($p, $loc, $db){
       $query = "SELECT area_ID FROM points WHERE point_ID = ".$p." AND location_ID = ".$loc;
       $result = $db->query($query);
       $result = $result->fetch_assoc();

       return $result["area_ID"];
   }

   function get_employee($request, $area, $db){
       $data = $request->getRequestVars();
       $point = htmlspecialchars($data["point"]);
       $location = htmlspecialchars($data["location"]);
       $query = "SELECT device_ID, phone_Type, employee_Phone FROM active_employees WHERE area_ID = ".$area." AND location_ID = ".$location;
       $result = $db->query($query);
       if($result->num_rows > 1){
           $employees = array();
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
               array_push($employees, $row);
           }
           return $employees;
       }
       if($result->num_rows == 1){
           return $result->fetch_assoc();
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility to log the requests which should be handled by php? It is too low information to give a senseful answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've added a log from my developer in the edit though it doesn't contain very much information. I've also added a good portion of the PHP file handling the POST call in case that helps. Let me know if I can provide any more information that may help.

Answer (score 0):

i think u getting is bunch of php code because whatever data u sending is not inserting in database. i think there can be two reasons.

problem in sending that data or there is problem in receiving data

Use the post method like below code

```
NSString *string=@"Your url";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *mpfBoundry = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=%@", mpfBoundry];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"]; 

    NSString* body =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"column1=%@&column2=%@&column3=%@", data1,data2,data3];

[request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[connection start];
```